# IBeacon Ionic, blank page

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ibeacon

So i'm currently following a tutorial for ibeacon 
https://ionicallyspeaking.com/2017/01/16/creating-a-beacon-application-with-ionic-2/

there are currently no error and i assume it works because the console says as stated in the image  [image]

However, once i've run on my device there's only blank page, what are the problem that i could probably facing?

Comment: Are you having any kind of errors? Try to see the console log while running on your device

Comment: @HumbertodeCarvalho no error, its just the apps won't detect any beacon